# can't see my site after ctrl-alt-delete in Virtual Machine Console

Tags: centos, vps, terminal

I'm a total newbie to this and hope you might be able to help me.

I just put my website up on a VPS server last week. I've been trying to get familiar with 
Terminal in Ubuntu and ssh for accessing the site, rather than shelling out more for
cPanel etc.

While browsing around my VPS settings yesterday I went into something called Virtual Machine Console.

A black command line looking screen opened up with:

CentOS release 6.2 (Final)
kernel 2.6.32-220 etc...

There were buttons at the top - 'Disconnect', 'Options', 'ClipBoard', 'Send Ctrl Alt Delete', 'Refresh'

Stupidly, I clicked the 'Send Ctrl Alt Delete', all this text started coming up on the screen 'Kill, Kill etc' and now my website is gone.

Later on in Terminal I ssh'd into the server and I can see all the files seem to be still there. The admin guy at the company said my server was just 
rebooting and it was up again - I was out of the office when he rang my mobile, but he made a mistake, it's still down.

I tried the 'Reboot' command a few times, but still no luck. So, I think everything is there, just no site. Any idea how to get it back?

Thanks for any help.

Chris.

Comment: Something is not clear in your question. You said you `ssh`d into the server after it rebooted and saw all your files there, but then you said that it's down. Which is it?

Comment: @MichaelHampton It reads as if the VPS is up and running, but the [expected] web site is unavailable. OP should probably indicate which web service they run, how they configured it to startup and what run level they're at, etc. :)

Comment: Is your web server (the daemon) set up to start automatically?

Comment: @Michael Hampton - can connect to server, but website is down.

Comment: @jscott. Not sure about what service I run. A Russian company set it up. Slow to get in touch unless I pay first. I have all priorities, if that's any help. http://www.letshost.ie/vps/packages/ - I'm on plan 2, if that's any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to see if the Apache HTTPD daemon is running:

```
sudo service httpd status
```

If it is not running, start the Apache HTTPD service:

```
sudo service httpd start
```

Finally, if the Apache HTTPD service wasn't running after restart you'll need to set the service to start automatically on startup:

```
sudo chkconfig httpd on
```

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for putting me on right track!When I type in 'sudo service httpd status' in terminal I get 'httpd is stopped'. So I type in 'service httpd start'. And I get Starting httpd: [Sat May 25 07:09:02 2013] [warn] module deflate_module is already loaded, skipping
[Sat May 25 07:09:02 2013] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs                [FAILED]
[app@populisto ~]$

Comment: You need to be root to start the service, just incase you did not already do it, try: sudo service httpd start

Comment: David Houde, you're a legend. It's back now. Thanks a lot.